The split from Christianity to socialism and liberalism
It appears that from Christianism there was a split between those who decided to emphasize the Christian idea of charity (love) (like Thomas More, Meslier, Saint-Simon, Cabet, Polanyi), which gave soil for socialism and communism (applying the social model of the monasteries to the whole society), and those who decided to emphasize the Christian idea of freedom and dignity (imago Dei), which gave soil to the protestant reformation, and liberalism (William of Ockham, Thomas Aquinas, School of Salamanca, Adam Smith, John Locke, Richard Cantillon).
Has this been recognized explicitly by some scientific researchers (academics)? I am not saying that the only source of socialism and liberalism is religion/Christianity.
References:
Ehrhardt, E. (1929). Idéologie communiste et christianisme. Revue d'Histoire et de Philosophie religieuses, 9(4), 341-365.
Hughes, G. (2011). The concept of dignity in the universal declaration of human rights. Journal of Religious Ethics, 39(1), 1-24.
McCloskey, D. N. (2016). Bourgeois equality: How ideas, not capital or institutions, enriched the world. University of Chicago Press.
Siedentop, L. (2014). Inventing the individual: The origins of western liberalism. Harvard University Press.
Vorster, N. (2012). A theological perspective on human dignity, equality and freedom. Verbum et Ecclesia, 33(1), 1-6.

(moved the question to SE Christianity, was downvoted 2 times, laughed at and closed. To be fair, some other members also engaged in providing interesting remarks.)

Lockley makes similar observations in the Oxford Handbook chapter analyzing Christian reactions to the 19th century social movements. For an unorthodox take, see The Protestant Ethic and the Spirit of Socialism (a play on Weber's famous title) who builds on Tawney's Religion and the Rise of Capitalism.

@Starckman Why was the question downvoted and mocked?

@JustSomeOldMan One comment was like "linking Thomas d'Aquin to liberalism is laughable"

Instead of deleting and reposting, please edit the original post. One thing we don't need is more clustered content

@PhilipKlöcking I express my apologies, I thought I closed/deleted my question (before moving it to Christianity SE, as kindly suggested by a user). Again, I'm sincerely sorry. Thank you for your intervention.
